# htaccess - Invalid directory on 301 redirect and virtualHost

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, redirect, subdomain

I have the following apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName files.example.com
 ServerAlias files.example.com dev.files.example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/example/files
</virtualHost>
```

and my .htaccess has:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)old-example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, if I point my browser to `files.old-example.com/myfile-1.2.zip` it's redirected to `files.example.com/files/myfile-1.2.zip` and obviously I get a `404` since the `files` directory does not exist within `/var/www/web/files`.

How can I redirect to `files.example.com/myfile-1.2.zip`? Please assume the same case would apply to different sub domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule as your very first in root .htaccess from a new browser:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.old-example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```